# How to query a path when only certain conditions are met?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have a graph that contains the following subgraph:

```
[a:A]-[r1:R1]->[b:B]-[r2:R2]->...->[y:Y]-[r25:R25]->[z:Z]
```

I want the query to return this subgraph but only when `y.allow` = 'yes'. How can I do this? How can I do this using shortestPath in neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
MATCH p = shortestPath((:A)-[*]-(:Y{allow: 'yes'})-[:R25]-(:Z))
RETURN p
```